# Airflow | print start time of a dag

Tags: python, date, time, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need `dag_run_start_date` to be a timestamp but from some reason it's different for each task. Anyone got solution for this?

I also want to know if it is possible to just print out the time of starting this `dag` or starting the first task.

What would be a correct approach in my situation?

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='maindag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 1),
    max_active_runs=1
)
dag_run_start_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
transfer_to_gcs = ContentToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id=f'transfer_to_gcs',
    content=getdata('people'),
    dst=f'people_{dag_run_start_date}.json',
    bucket='bucketname',
    dag=dag
)


transfer_to_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id=f'transfer_to_bq',
    bucket='bucketname',
    source_objects=[f'people_{dag_run_start_date}.json'],
    dag=dag
)


transfer_to_gcs >> transfer_to_bq
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Airflow [templating feature](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

The reason is your DAG file code is executed only to define the tasks which need to be run, it's not executed every time the DAG is run.

eg. Something more like the following:

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='maindag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 1),
    max_active_runs=1
)

transfer_to_gcs = ContentToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id=f'transfer_to_gcs',
    content=getdata('people'),
    dst='people_{{ ts_nodash }}.json',
    bucket='bucketname',
    dag=dag
)

transfer_to_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id=f'transfer_to_bq',
    bucket='bucketname',
    source_objects=['people_{{ ts_nodash }}.json'],
    dag=dag
)

transfer_to_gcs >> transfer_to_bq
```

Comment: Thanks but this actually returns a file named exactly 'people_{{ ts_nodash }}.json'

Comment: Do you mean for `transfer_to_gcs` task? I cannot find any docs for this operator ContentToGoogleCloudStorageOperator, but some fields maybe not templated. This `dst` field seems important for template, so you should ask maintainer to adjust the operator. If not maybe use another operator. eg. Bash operator can run gsutil command to write file to GCS.

Comment: yes, templating didnt work but i used xcom instead